# Импорт данных

Tags: php, mysql

Есть механизм импорта данных в базу.
На сервер загружается csv файл с id товара новой ценой.
В цикле for перебираюся все строки csv файла.
Если id не пустой то делается UPDATE цены по известному id.

Проблема в том, что работает это только с маленькими файлами, до 100 позиций, все остальные варианты не отрабатывают до конца, но и в error_log ничего не пишится, типа превышение лимита ресурсов и т.д.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что скрипту не хватает 30 сек и автоматом тушится? Или здесь срабатывает какое-то ограничение на количество запросов к базе?

Как лучше переделать систему импорта?

Код

```
$p = file($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/i.csv");
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($p); $i++)
{
    $e = explode(';', $p[$i]);  
    $id = $e[0];
    $price = $e[1];
    mysql_query("UPDATE products SET price='$price' WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

Основной вопрос в том как не плодить кучу запросов UPDATE в цикле и провести обновление пакетно.
Есть вариант делать это пошагово, т.е. читать файл пошагово и пошагово обновлять, скажем по 50 позиций, но это не решает проблемы лимита запросов к бд.
Использовать mysqli_ multi_query возможности нет.

Comment: Кстати, если ошибки в настройках пхп не отключены, то если таймаут выполнения скрипта превышен, то это будет выведено в браузер!

Comment: @Зоркий, а <a href="http://habrahabr.ru/qa/1154/">мультиапдейт</a> вам не нравится? По крайней мере, будет обновляться все или ничего.

Comment: Идея нравится но не сработает, я ниже в камментах подробно расписал почему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всего то нужно было поле Id сделать индексным, коим оно не являлось. Проблема сразу же отпала и файл в 500 строк импортировался менее чем за секунду. Отсутствие индексного поля очень негативно сказалось на производительности запросов Апдейт.

Answer (score 2):

А попробуйте тоже самое, только стандартной `fgetcsv();` я думаю, что всё получится ;)

Comment: fgetcsv(); проблему не решила, однако, это хороший вариант оптимизации :). Я её как-то проглядел, получая строку fgets-ом и дальше explode её.

Comment: Ещё, как вариант оптимизации нужно в 1 итерации делать 2 команды. Тоже очень снижает нагрузку. Что-то типа
 
    for($i=0; $i<=count($arr); $i++++){  
        mysql_query("UPDATE `table` WHERE `id`=".$i." SET ...");  
        mysql_query("UPDATE `table` WHERE `id`=".$i+1." SET ...");
    }

Надеюсь, поможет!

Comment: Такая мысль приходила в голову, но это не решает проблемы. Всё равно срабатывает лимит запросов к БД.

Comment: Mysql-запросы лучше "скармливать" пачками штук по 30-50. У меня недавно была задача: "парсинг XML", такой способ сберёг больше половины времени!

Comment: Как реализовали "скормку" пачками?

Comment: что-то вроде:  
    $update = "INSERT INTO `products` (code, price) VALUES ";
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $update .= "(".$array['key']['code'].",".$array['key']['price']."),";
    }
$update = substr($update, 0, -1);
$update .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE products.price = VALUES(price);"  
mysql_query($update);  
Вот как-то так. Он вставки сделает того, чего нет. Те, что обновлять не нужно - не тронет. Остальные обновит.

Comment: хммм, у меня такой запрос пачка не проходит, phpmyadmin его выполянет, а из скрипта ошибка вываливается в sql синтасисе :/
Недавно заливал циклом 9к позиций, менее 2-х секунд на всё ушло, я в целом доволен :)

Comment: может тогда уже мне "галочку" поставить и вопрос закрыть?! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, не обращайтесь 1000 раз к базе. Постройте один запрос типа

```sql
insert into products(id, price) 
values 
    ($id1, $price1), 
    ($id2, $price2)... on duplicate key update price=$price
```

(предполагается, что `id` - уникальный ключ)

или, если запрос ооочень большой, сгруппируйте хотя-бы 20-50 продуктов на запрос...
Скорее всего Вы тратите время именно на множественные обращения к базе...

**Еще два решения:**

-1- Воспользоваться [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://litecode.ru/load_data_infile.shtml) и, при необходимости, такой [конструкцией](http://www.askdev.ru/mysql/2461/LOAD-DATA-INFILE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-mysql/):

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable ( ID int, column1 text, column2 text ) TYPE=HEAP; 
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name' INTO TABLE TempTable;
INSERT INTO ResultTable SELECT column1, column2 FROM TempTable;
DROP TABLE TempTable;
```

`insert` заменить на `update` с `join` или с `where exists()`... например:

```sql
update products 
inner join temp_new_prices on products.id=temp_new_prices.id 
set products.price=temp_new_prices.price;
```

-2- Передать в хранимую процедуру MySQL огромную строку, содержащую n продуктов и цен, и далее, уже в хранимой процедуре, в цикле распарсить ее.... Решение приводить не буду - громоздкое. Но если нужно (и не найдете в гугле) - пишите.

Comment: Да, в этом и есть основная проблема. Есть ли другие варианты построения мультизапроса к mysql? Приведенный пример, я думаю не подойдет, потому что некоторых товаров в базе может не быть, соответственно запрос не отработает. Каково максимальное кол-во запросов которое можно сгруппировать?

Comment: В такой ситуации могу только посоветовать попробовать составить строку из многих update ... where ...,;, и использовать mysqli_multi_query (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) или стандартный mysql_query, но нужно проверить опции подключения (выполнение нескольких запросов "в одном")

Comment: Множественный UPDATE через mysql_query() MySQL к превиликому сожалению не поддерживает. Поэтому остается только mysqli_multi_query() использовать. Перегуглил всё но нет упоминаний как это сделать приминительно для запроса на UPDATE, + если запись не обновилась этот момент зафиксировать.

Comment: Есть еще два решения - добавил в ответ.

Comment: Вариант с LOAD DATA INFILE очень интересный (на хабре есть готовый пример с импортом), возможно, у меня дойдут руки до полного осмысления процесса и его тестирования. 

С хранимыми процедурами никогда не работал и как-то лезсть в них аще не хочется. Тем не менее большое спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

Не читайте построчно, читайте в массив. Массивы обрабатываются гораздо быстрее.

```
$fp = fopen ("i.csv","r") or die ( "Не удалось открыть файл парсинга" );
/* Читаем построчно */
while ($data = fgetcsv ($fp,4000,"^","~")){Здесь обработка каждой строки}
```

Comment: Да, так и сделал.

Answer (score 1):

А как вы итаете данные из файла?
Если file_get_content or readfile - то на больших файлах не хватит оперативной памяти.

На счет времени поставьте в начале файла set_time_limit(0)

А файл читайте так:

```
$handle=fopen($fileName,'r');
if($handle){
    while($string=fgets($handle)){
        ...work...
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Если скрипт не оч. большой, приведите его код.

Comment: Код приложил.
Проблем с памятью при открытии файла нет, даже если там 5 000 строк. Мне кажется узкое место в БД. Но тогда почему нет ошибок в error_log-e.

Comment: Попробуйте if(!mysql_query("UPDATE products SET price='$price' WHERE id = '$id'"))print mysql_error();

Comment: $price поступает абсолютно точно типа инт. До 100 запросов проходит а далее белая страница, ни ошибкок, варнингов - ничего и error-log пуст. Попробую ваш совет, хотя set_time_limit(0) точно не отработает - такой хостинг.